# $(\alpha, \infty]$ as a union of open sets.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I would like to show that $(\alpha, \infty]$ is a Borel set using the definition of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. I'm having trouble with including the infinity, because $\bigcup_n (\alpha, n) = (\alpha, \infty)$. If I work with the complements of $[-\infty, \alpha]$, I'm having trouble approaching infinity too.

I know this is trivial, I just need a hint.

Thanks!

Comment: By definition, $(\alpha,\infty]$ is an open neighourhood of $\infty$.

Comment: Daniel, from wikipedia, I get this: "Note that the neighbourhood V need not be an open set itself. If V is open it is called an open neighbourhood". So, to say that it is an open neighbourhood, I need first to prove that it is an open set, right?

Comment: That's how the topology on $[-\infty,\infty]$ is - usually, at least - defined. If you work with a different (definition of the) topology, it might not be open. What's the definition you're working with?

Comment: You're right, I assumed only that $(a, b)$ are the open sets, but I should have looked at the topology itself. Now, I can't seem to find a simple definition of a topology on the extended real line, but as far as I understand, it is the topology induced by the intervals $(a, b)$ plus, the intervals of the type $[-\infty, a)$ and $(a, \infty]$. Though, I don't completely understand it: $\infty$ seems to be an endpoint and what do we do with $(a, \infty)$?

Comment: $(a,\infty)$ is open too. It's however not a neighbourhood of $\infty$. The topology on $[-\infty,\infty]$ is the topology it gets from $[-1,1]$ by the bijection (homeomophism) $h\colon x \mapsto \frac{x}{1-\lvert x\rvert}$ with the obvious extension of $h$ to $\pm 1$.

Comment: @Daniel: You could convert these comments into an answer and get this question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition of the topology on the extended real line $[-\infty,+\infty]$, a set of the form $(\alpha,+\infty]$ is open, hence it is a Borel set.

A common way to define the topology on $[-\infty,+\infty]$ is by specifying a bijection to a compact interval $\subset \mathbb{R}$, e.g. $h\colon [-1,1] \to [-\infty,+\infty];\quad h(x) = \frac{x}{1-\lvert x\rvert}$ for $-1 < x < 1$ and $h(-1) = -\infty;\; h(1) = +\infty$, and positing that the bijection be a homeomorphism, i.e. declaring a subset $U \subset [-\infty,+\infty]$ open if and only if $h^{-1}(U)$ is open in $[-1,1]$. Familiarity with the interval gives (hopefully) a good help dealing with $[-\infty,+\infty]$ as a topological space.

Another common way is to define neighbourhoods, then the points of $\mathbb{R}\subset [-\infty,+\infty]$ have their usual neighbourhood bases, and neighbourhood bases of $\pm\infty$ are given by sets of the form $(\alpha,+\infty]$ resp. $[-\infty, \alpha)$. It is a good exercise to verify that this construction yields the same topology as the other one.